# Cheap cloud functions with database

Tags: amazon, google

In AWS there are decently priced cloud functions (AWS Lambda), but in practice they are costly because they usually to be used together with a database, and the database service *requires* in some weird reason a multi-CPU instance what is too costly for start level and testing.

What alternatives to AWS Lambda + AWS Database exist?

What about GCP Functions? about GCP database (does Google provide start-level databases with just 1 CPU and other lightweight parameters)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you’re looking for a relational database and have very little DB load, you could look into Aurora Serverless. Also, if you don’t mind managing the DB server yourself, you could set up MySQL on a free tier instance.

If you are open to nonrelational databases, you should consider DynamoDB which can be more cost effective by orders of magnitude depending on your use case. To learn more about DynamoDB, I can recommend this YT series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k2GINpO308&list=PL9nWRykSBSFi5QD8ssI0W5odL9S0309E2&index=1